# C++ Transparent Client Area

Tags: c++, winapi, window, transparent

I am attempting to create a program where, when I click a button on the main window, a secondary invisible window pops up, with drawings on them, hence the images appearing as if they are floating. For some reason however, no part of the "invisible" window becomes transparent. The code for declaring the window class is:

```
const char g_szClassName2[] = "invisWindow";
WNDCLASSEX invisWindowClass;
HWND invisHWnd;

invisWindowClass.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
invisWindowClass.style          = WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
invisWindowClass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProcedure2;
invisWindowClass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
invisWindowClass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
invisWindowClass.hInstance     = hInstance;
invisWindowClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
invisWindowClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
invisWindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
invisWindowClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
invisWindowClass.lpszClassName = g_szClassName2;
invisWindowClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

RegisterClassEx(&invisWindowClass);
```

I included the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style, which I believed would make my client area invisible.

The code inside the BUTTON CLICK case statement of the invisible window's CALLBACK WndProcedure2 is:

```
                const char g_szClassName2[] = "invisWindow";
                const char WndName2[] = "invisible Window";

                HWND invisWindowHandle = CreateWindowEx(0,
                      g_szClassName2,
                      WndName2,
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                      200,
                      200,
                      800,
                      500,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL);


                ShowWindow(invisWindowHandle, 3);
                UpdateWindow(invisWindowHandle);
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: [Like the cake, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT is a lie, or at least not the entire truth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/17/10378525.aspx)

Comment: `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` doesn't by itself make the window transparent. All it does is make sure windows under yours are painted first, so your window has a chance of creating an effect of transparency by choosing not to paint certain pixels. Your window, however, paints its whole background using `COLOR_WINDOW` brush.

Comment: Perhaps the [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API is what you're looking for.  You can construct arbitrary region(s) to define the part of your window that displays and is response to the UI.

Comment: Or for more complex effects, `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` and `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Comment: See some of my answers here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/481856/win32-how-make-the-form-transparent-and-opacy  IIRC, that guy was attempting the same thing.

Comment: All great comments guys. Funny comment with the cake from Portal lolz. @ChrisO Chris if I were to use that function, could I continuously use it throughout the programs runtime? Id like to make images pop up, disappear, and so forth.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, though you might have to all it often to update with new regions to match your desired effects.